# Pag.Previous page returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have tried many times and in different ways to see why "Page.PreviousPage" returns null but I did not get anywhere. I checked most of posts here in stackoverflow and some other website. None of them worked. Anybody has any idea? Following is the asp code in the source page which I named it "sourcePage.aspx".It shows the button that does the cross page post:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnCrossPagePostBack" runat="server" Text="Cross page post back navigation" PostBackUrl="~/targetPage.aspx" Width="270px"/>
```

The following is the code in the target page which I named it "targetPage.aspx":

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      Page previousPage = Page.PreviousPage;            
            if (previousPage != null && previousPage.IsCrossPagePostBack)
            {
                lblName.Text =   ((TextBox)previousPage.FindControl("txtName")).Text;
                lblEmail.Text = ((TextBox)previousPage.FindControl("txtEmail")).Text;
            }
            else
            {
                lblStat.Text = "You loaded this page using a technique other than Cross Page Post Back";
            }
}
```

"txtName" and "txtEmail" are two text boxes in the source page. I know how to do this by using "Server.Transfer" or Strongly typed reference. I am looking for doing by Corss page post back and not any other way. Somebody said I should use Empty page and then add web forms and not template web forms but there is not empty page and visual studio only provides web forms. Any clue?
Thanks!

Comment: The point was correct. When you want to start a new project you should choose "Empty" and not "Web Form" or etc.

Answer (score 0):

The point was correct. When you want to start a new project you should choose "Empty" and not "Web Form" or etc.